# Is there an open source with MIT license implementation of a CSPRNG with seeding written in C#?

Tags: random-number-generator

I need a CSPRNG written in C# that has seeding functionality but I can't find any implementation out there that seems legit. The only one I found is [prangster](https://github.com/cmars/prangster) but it has some requirements to be used. Does anyone know a good and free implementation?

Comment: Sorry, we don't really do software recommendations on this website.

Comment: That said, the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) crypto library is MIT licensed and has a C# API that includes several CSPRNGs. It's also widely used and has a pretty decent reputation IME.

Comment: I didn't know. Thank you for your recommendations.